# How do I display prettyprinted JSON in a React component?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have this ES6 React component:

```
class KeyDetails extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <p className="layout__item u-1/2-lap-and-up">
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.details, null, 2)}
            </p>
        )
    }
}
```

But all of the newlines and quotation marks appear encoded.

[image]

How can I display raw, nicely formatted text via React?

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you're wanting to preserve whitespace on formatted text, the appropriate tag to use is `<pre />`, so:

```
class KeyDetails extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <pre className="layout__item u-1/2-lap-and-up">
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.details, null, 2)}
            </pre>
        )
    }
}
```

Regarding the encoding: Its hard to say given the information. This fiddle, for example, works.

https://jsfiddle.net/2mtrj0a3/1/

Comment: What version of react is in that jsfiddle? I changed to pre, but it didn't work. My app has 0.13.3.

Comment: `0.14.6`. But https://jsfiddle.net/1208gq4x/1/ also seems to work and its using `0.13.3`